# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in React navigation 4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this screen NewsTabScreen.js

```
class NewsTabScreen extends Component {
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return (
  <Container style={style.container}>
    <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab tabsContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? '#F8F8F8' : '#3F51B5'}}/>}>
    <Tab heading={
      <TabHeading>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{I18n.t("news")}</Text>
      </TabHeading>}>
      <News/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading={
      <TabHeading>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{I18n.t("newsOfCommittees")}</Text>
      </TabHeading>}>
      <ComNews/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading={
      <TabHeading>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{I18n.t("requests")}</Text>
      </TabHeading>}>
    <RequestsNews/>
    </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </Container>
);}}
```

when I click item on the news, I get an error

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wrap your `News` component with `withNavigation` if it is not part of any navigator but you still want to access `navigation`, Take a look at document [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation.html)

Like

```
class News extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default withNavigation(News);
```

Hope this will help!